# How do I make my spatial index use a Level greater than HIGH?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial, spatial-index

My spatial geography index in SQL Server has the following level definitions.

HIGH LOW LOW LOW

The problem is that all of my points are in a city and thus all of my points are in a single cell at layer 1. As a result the primary filter is looking at all points which means my index efficiency is 0%. I realized that the HIGH grid means that there are 256 cells. How do I instead use 512 cells or 1024 cells? 256 just isn't enough for me.

[Take a look at this page for the different levels.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964712.aspx#ctl00_MTCS_main_ctl36_ctl00_ctl03)

Does anyone know how to get a higher value than HIGH?

Comment: Have you tried changing CELLS_PER_OBJECT parameter?

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov That only applies to polygon objects from my understanding and not points.

Comment: If all your points are within a small area, would it not be better to use the GEOMETRY data type, specifying the bounding area around the city, your chosen projection system?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is the right answer.

Comment: Why are you specifying HLLL to begin with, instead of HHHH? Using HHHH should still improve resolution even if all points are still in the same root cell.

Comment: I was unable to see any performance difference by setting HHHH vs HLLL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bounding box (see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196(v=sql.105).aspx for information about bounding boxes).

Without a bounding box: The issue is that the SQL Server uses a sub-gridding methodology. The 256 cells together must span the entire space! This means that you HLLL is restricting the number of cells you use. Think about it this way: The LLL portion creates 4096 cells for each of the initial cells. The 256 cells each must be the same size. That means that your high level cells are splitting up too large of an area!

Instead, if you put in a bounding box, the total area covered will be reduced, and the 4096 grids will be smaller, so splitting that into 256 can be sufficient.